# Smart cast (automatic type promotion) using 'is' is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the Bloc pattern and have the following code to define my states:

```dart
import 'package:meta/meta.dart'

@immutable
abstract class UiState {}

class Loading extends UiState {}

class Success extends UiState {
  Success(this.message);

  final String message;
}

class Failure extends UiState {}
```

I try to use a `UiState` as follows:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.uiState,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final UiState uiState;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (uiState is Success) {
      return Text(uiState.message);
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

But VSCode tells me that "The getter 'message' isn't defined for the class 'UiState'".

I've used smart casts before and they did work. But in this instance, I'm not able to figure out why it's not working.

My pubspec has the following:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
```

So, I assume my dart version is atleast 2.1.0.

Comment: To work around this issue as of the time of asking this question, I'm casting `uiState` explicitly inside the `if`s. Which is non-ideal given that the language supports smart casts.

Comment: Another workaround would be storing the state inside a local variable such as `final currentState = uiState;` and using `currentState` in your if statement.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`is` performs implicit type promotion only for local variables and (as of Dart 3.2) instance variables that are both `final` and private.

For such variables, the compiler can deduce that the value of the variable will not be change between the time that its type is checked with `is` and before the variable is used.

For instance variables that can be reassigned or are public or for other non-local variables, the compiler cannot easily make that guarantee.  All non-local variables implicitly provide getter functions, which could be overridden by a derived class and which could return different values from one access to the next.

Also see:

- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/21530
- https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34480

As an alternative to an explicit cast, you of course could store the non-local variable in a local variable first.  For example:

```dart
void memberFunction() {
  final memberVariable = this.memberVariable;
  if (memberVariable is Person) {
    memberVariable.firstName = 'Bob';
  }
}
```

Note that [this also applies to type promotion from nullable to non-nullable types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035574/), such as when doing `if (someNullableVariable != null)`.

Also see https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons for some other reasons why automatic type promotion might not occur.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `BlocProvider` but you have not wrapped your widget/scaffold with `BlocProvider` and `BlocBuilder`.

Do it like this:

```
 BlocProvider(
                create: (final context) => SubjectBloc(),
                child: BlocBuilder<SubjectBloc, SubjectState>(
                  builder: (final context, final state) {
                    if (state is Success) {
                      return const Text('data');
                    }
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  },
                ),
              ),
```