# Null check doesn't cause type promotion in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, type-promotion

I'm upgrading a personal package that is based on the Flutter framework. I noticed [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart#L558) in the Flutter Text widget source code that there is a null check:

```dart
if (textSpan != null) {
  properties.add(textSpan!.toDiagnosticsNode(name: 'textSpan', style: DiagnosticsTreeStyle.transition));
}
```

However, `textSpan!` is still using the `!` operator. Shouldn't `textSpan` be promoted to a non-nullable type without having to use the `!` operator? However, trying to remove the operator gives the following error:

> ```
> An expression whose value can be 'null' must be null-checked before it can be dereferenced.
> Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before dereferencing it.
> ```

Here is a self-contained example:

```dart
class MyClass {
  String? _myString;
  
  String get myString {
    if (_myString == null) {
      return '';
    }
    
    return _myString; //   <-- error here
  }
}
```

I get a compile-time error:

> Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be returned from function 'myString' because it has a return type of 'String'.

Or if I try to get `_mySting.length` I get the following error:

> The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.

I thought doing the null check would promote `_myString` to a non-nullable type. Why doesn't it?

[My question](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44327) was solved on GitHub so I'm posting an answer below.

Comment: This is basically another version of https://stackoverflow.com/q/56764592/ (I'm sure there are other existing questions too).

Comment: @jamesdlin, that's interesting. I didn't realize this was more generalized than just null safety.

Comment: I mentioned it in [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56764992/), but it's probably worth pointing out here too: this is covered by https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Dart engineer Erik Ernst [says on GitHub](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44327#issuecomment-734704925):

> Type promotion is only applicable to local variables. ... Promotion of an instance variable is not sound, because it could be overridden by a getter that runs a computation and returns a different object each time it is invoked. Cf. [dart-lang/language#1188](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1188) for discussions about a mechanism which is similar to type promotion but based on dynamic checks, with some links to related discussions.

So local type promotion works:

```dart
  String myMethod(String? myString) {
    if (myString == null) {
      return '';
    }
    
    return myString;
  }
```

But instance variables that aren't `final` and that aren't private don't get promoted. (Prior to Dart 3.2, non-local variables never got promoted.) For that you need to manually tell Dart that you are sure that the instance variable isn't null in this case by using the `!` operator:

```dart
class MyClass {
  String? _myString;
  
  String myMethod() {
    if (_myString == null) {
      return '';
    }
    
    return _myString!;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can `myMethod` be rewritten as `String myMethod() { return _myString ?? '' }`?

Comment: @gegobyte, Yes (if you add a semicolon).

Answer (score 33):

#### The Error:

Let's say, this is your code and you're doing a null check on the instance variable and still seeing an error:

```dart
class Foo {
  int? x;

  double toDouble() {
    if (x != null) return x.toDouble(); // <-- Error
    return -1;
  }
}
```

> The method 'toDouble' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

The error you see in code like this is because **Getters are not promoted to their non-nullable counterparts**. Let's talk about the reason why.

---

#### Reason of the Error:

Let's say, there's a class `Bar` which extends `Foo` and overrides `x` field and implemented like this:

```dart
class Bar extends Foo {
  @override
  int? get x => (++_count).isOdd ? 1 : null;
  int _count = 0;
}
```

Now, if you do

```dart
Bar().toDouble();
```

You would have run into a runtime null error, which is why getters type promotion is prohibited.

---

#### Solutions:

We need to cast away nullability from `int?`. There are generally 3 ways to do this.

- **Use local variable (Recommended)**

  ```dart
  double toDouble() {
    final x = this.x; // <-- Use a local variable
    if (x != null) return x.toDouble(); 
    return -1;
  }
  ```
- **Use `?.` with `??`**

  ```dart
  double toDouble() {
    return x?.toDouble() ?? -1; // Provide a default value
  }
  ```
- **Use null-assertion operator (!)**

  You should only use this solution when you're 100% sure that the variable (`x`) will never be `null`.

  ```dart
  double toDouble() {
    return x!.toDouble(); // Null assertion operator
  }
  ```

Comment: The local variable solution looks like the best option, especially when you need to use += or *= operators

Comment: Details on documentation:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators

Comment: Is the solution to use a local variable your personal recommendation, or has the dart team said anything about it?

Comment: @HannesHultergård It's coming from a post written by one of the members of Dart team.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but unless I'm missing something fundamental here, I feel that this example doesn't really illustrate the reasoning behind preventing getter promotion, since `i` obviously never changes after the null check.


Wouldn't a better example for `i` in `Bar` be 
`int? get i => Random().nextBool() ? 0 : null;`
like the one shown [here](https://youtu.be/HdKwuHQvArY?t=1671)?
 

This way, you can really see how the compiler could never guarantee that `i` isn't null, since its value can change to null when it's accessed after the null check.

Comment: @OmarSharaki You're right. I've updated the code.