# dart nullability checking method

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

I have a method `bool isNotEmpty(dynamic e)`, where i check nullability myself based on few criteria (`e.toString() == null.toString()`, `e.length` for `String`'s and `List`'s, etc.). my question is, I have a piece of code like this:

```
String e = 'a';
if (isNotEmpty(e)) {
   print(e);
}
```

how do I let **dart** be aware that the `isNotEmpty` method is ensuring that `e` is not null, and do not have to write `print(e!)` for every use of the method?

Comment: Darts flow analysis only works on `local variables` and doesn't work on `class members`. So this might not be possible as of now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess we'll have to wait.

Comment: Let's see if someone else comes up with something.

Comment: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#working-with-nullable-fields

Comment: @Adnan Check if this answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65456958/dart-null-safety-doesnt-work-with-class-fields

Comment: I don't think this question is related to "promoting fields". It's still not possible in the current Dart. You cannot link the boolean returned by a function to any property of an argument in such a way that local analysis can then infer that property from the return value. There is simply no functionality to do so.