# How to fix "The operator ‘{0}’ can’t be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be ‘null’"

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

While trying **Dart**'s *Sound Null Safety* i came up with a problem:

---

### Some Context

Creating a new **Flutter** project i found the following (and very familiar) piece code

```dart
int _counter = 0;

void _incrementCounter() {
  setState(() {
    // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
    // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
    // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
    // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
    // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
    _counter++;
  });
}
```

Now, i changed the variable `_counter` to be *nullable* and took off the initialization:

```dart
int? _counter;

void _incrementCounter() {
  setState(() {
    _counter++;
  });
}
```

And as expected, i got the following error in the editor:

> The operator ‘+’ can’t be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

### The Problem

Following [the documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#unchecked_use_of_nullable_value) i added the required checking:

```dart
if (_counter!=null)
        _counter++;
```

but to my astonishment, the error kept on showing and suggesting

> Try making the call conditional (using '?' or adding a null check to the target ('!'))

even though i explicitly am making *the call conditionally*... so what is wrong?

Comment: `if (_counter != null) _counter = _counter! + 1;`

Comment: @Dude, "using ! comes with a loss of static safety" [https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#null-assertion-operator]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### UPDATE

As suggested in [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035574/null-check-doesnt-cause-type-promotion-in-dart), in [a further thread in Github](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44327#issuecomment-734704925) Erik Ernst says:

> Type promotion is only applicable to local variables... Promotion of an instance variable is not sound, because it could be overridden by a getter that runs a computation and returns a different object each time it is invoked. Cf. [dart-lang/language#1188](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1188) for discussions about a mechanism which is similar to type promotion but based on dynamic checks, with some links to related discussions.

So, with that explanation, now i see that only local variables can (so far?) be [*promoted*](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#type-promotion-on-null-checks), and thus my problem could be fixed by writing

```
int? _counter;

void _incrementCounter() {
  setState(() {
    if (_counter!=null)
        _counter = _counter! + 1;
  });
}
```

For an alternative fix, see my original answer below.

---

### The *other* Fix

I finally fixed the problem by capturing the value of the instance variable inside the method as follows:

```dart
int? _counter;

void _incrementCounter() {
  setState(() {
    var c = _counter;

    if (c!=null)
      c++;

    _counter = c;
      
  });
}
```

### Why the need to capture the variable?

Well, the whole problem is that

> Type promotion is only applicable to local variables... Promotion of an instance variable is not sound, because it could be overridden by a getter that runs a computation and returns a different object each time it is invoked

so in my approach we

- *capture* the value of the instance variable
- then we check for **that** *value* to not be null.
- if that value turned out not to be null then we operate on the local variable which through the null check is now correctly promoted.
- finally we apply the new value to the instance variable.

### Final observations

I am new to **Dart** and thus i am not 100% sure, but to me it seems that *in general*, when working with nullable instace variables, my approach is better that that of using the bang operator to *cast away nullity*:

By casting away nullity you are overlooking the main problem of promoting instance variables, namely that

> it could be overridden by a getter that runs a computation and returns a different object each time it is invoked ...

That exact problem is what is avoided by *capturing* the value of the instance variable and working with **that** locally captured value...

If i am wrong kindly let me know...