# How to increment/decrement a nullable expression in Dart's Sound Null Safety: `<nullable_variable>!++`?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am using the ***Sound Null Safety*** in **Dart**, and i have the following code

```dart
int? _counter;

void _incrementCounter() {
  setState(() {
    if (_counter!=null)
      _counter++;
  });
}
```

Now, since _counter is not a local variable, it can not be promoted (see [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66472892/7432242) to see why), so i have to tell **Dart** i am sure `_counter` is not null by adding the *bang operator* (`!`). Thus i wrote

```dart
_counter!++;
```

but that does not work: i get the error message

> Illegal assignment to non-assignable expression.

So, is there a way to get around this without the need to explicitly write

```dart
_counter = _counter! + 1;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's working as intended *today* and you have to use `_counter = _counter! + 1;` if you keep `int?` as type of `_counter`.

In the future this could change regarding the proposal [Dart Null-Asserting Composite Assignment](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/53f3e4606f7efe25679c37698e167734df7f934c/working/1113%20-%20null-asserting%20compound%20assignment/proposal.md)
.

Comment: If you came here and would like to see this change in syntax please go to https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1113# and add some noise!

Comment: this is something very basic and fundamental, but sometimes in the rush of everyday life we forget details like this. thank you friend.