# Accessing nested property in AsyncSnapshot

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

So, I am learning to use the [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) class in `Flutter`. My code works, but I wonder if I could improve the way I access the data from the snapshot.
My `FutureBuilder` is like that:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<ListCard>>(
          future: items,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: _pullRefresh,
              child: _listView(snapshot),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

`items` is a class property of type `Future<List<ListCard>>`. `_listView` is the method where I work on the snapshot. There are 2 errors in this code:

```
  Widget _listView(AsyncSnapshot<List<ListCard>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data != null) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length, // Error when accessing the length property
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return snapshot.data[index]; // Error when accessing the index
        },
      );
    } else {
      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }
  }
```

The two errors are actually the same. They say:

> The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the
> receiver can be 'null'. Try making the access conditional (using '?.')
> or adding a null check to the target
> ('!').dart(unchecked_use_of_nullable_value)

I understand that `snapshot.data` is of type `List<ListCard>?`, therefore its value can either be `null` or a list of type `List<ListCard>`. In case the value is null, Flutter will display the `CircularProcessIndicator`. If it's not null, then the `ListView.builder` widget will be returned. If we reach that point, `snapshot.data` is always a list (it's been tested in the if statement) and it should therefore have a length property.

I also tried:

```
Widget _listView(AsyncSnapshot<List<ListCard>> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.data is List<ListCard>) {
  //...
}
```

but it gives exactly the same error.
Same story with:

```
Widget _listView(AsyncSnapshot<List<ListCard>> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasData) {
  //...
}
```

However I can get rid of these errors by adding the `!` operator:

```
//...
itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return snapshot.data![index];
},
//...
```

I could also do a type assertion such as `List<ListCard> data = snapshot.data as List<ListCard>;` but I don't want to go that way.

Is it possible to make this work without using the `!` operator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you handle your `builder` is wrong, try this:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
          return Text('Loading....');
        default:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
          } else {
            List<ListCard> data = snapshot.data ?? [];
            return RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: _pullRefresh,
              child: _listView(data),
            );
          }
      }
},
```

here I set default value for `data`, if it gets null I will pass empty list.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but i believe `data = snapshot.data ?? [];` uses `data = snapshot.data!` under the hood...

Comment: @deczaloth I don't think so, because when you use `!` on null value it will through exception but when you use  `?? []` it will not.

Comment: you only can use `!` when your 100 % sure that your variable isn't null, but the way OP handle the  the different state of `FutureBuilder`, they will get null issue. @deczaloth

Comment: You are right, but what i was trying to say is that when `??` finds out `snapshot.data` is not null, it does not simply set `data = snapshot.data`, but has to set instead `data = snapshot.data!`.

Comment: I understand what you said, but what I try to say is that these operators are not the same but both of the lead to same result but with different scenario, in `data = snapshot.data!` you tell the compiler that this data is not null so in the back it use `data = snapshot.data` but in `data = snapshot.data ?? []` you tell that this is the data but if it was null you take the default value, so these aren't same. @deczaloth

Comment: As i see it, 
`data = snapshot.data ?? [];`
translates to 
`if (snapshot.data != null) { data = snapshot.data!;
} else { data = [];
}`

Answer (score 3):

I presume the problem you are facing is because `snapshot` can not be promoted to non nullable.

In your case you will have to go using "**!**" after a null-check.

Remember

> Type promotion is only applicable to local variables... Promotion of
> an instance variable is not sound, because it could be overridden by a
> getter that runs a computation and returns a different object each
> time it is invoked. Cf. dart-lang/language#1188 for discussions about
> a mechanism which is similar to type promotion but based on dynamic
> checks, with some links to related discussions.

For further information on this topic see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66472892/7432242).

Comment: Thank you, your link gives a pretty good explanation to my problem