# Which pattern should I use to throw specific errors when a variable is null in dart?

Tags: dart

I currently use:

```
  int get displayFlex => displaySegment == null
      ? throw StateError("Note is not yet processed by the Widget")
      : displaySegment!.flex;
```

The fact that I need to use `!` after `displaySegment!` makes me think that there might be a better way to write this code. Is there a better pattern?

Comment: The reason why you need to use `!` is because [non-local variables won't get type promoted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035574/).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about "better", but:

```dart
int get displayFlex => 
  (displaySegment ?? throw StateError("Note is not yet processed by the Widget")).flex;
```

is *valid*.

I'd probably do the more elaborate and readable

```dart
int get displayFlex {
  var displaySegment = this.displaySegment;
  if (displaySegment == null) throw StateError("Note is not yet processed by the Widget");
  return displaySegment.flex;
}
```