# "receiver can be null" when it can't?

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I just finished my nullsafe migration. I'm finding that wrapping code with a null check only sometimes removes the need for the nullcheck `!` operator? E.g.,

```
class MyClass {
  double divideBy4(double numerator) {
    return numerator / 4;
  }

  double quarteredWorks(double? value) {
    if (value != null)
      return divideBy4(value); // <- no intellisense warning
    else
      return 0;
  }

  double quarteredDoesntWork(double? value) {
      return divideBy4(value); // <- intellisense: "double? can't be assigned to double"
  }

  double? value;

  double divideBy2() {
    if (value != null)
      return value / 2; // <- intellisense: "receiver can be null"
    else
      return .0;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Changed my example to show an example of wrapping with a null check that works

Comment: Your `value` can be null as it's defined `double?`. The null safety is here to avoid checking null values. Here, the check is not enough as the `value` var can be null. You can tell the compiler that you are sure the value is not null thanks to your manual check by using the `!` operator. Checking with an if statement does not override the nullability of the variable from its definition (it's just my understanding, I didn't thing a thing about that in the doc).

Comment: This might be related to Intellisense which does not infer the type correctly, by copy/pasting your code into DartPad with nullsafety enabled I don't have any warning.

Comment: @Maxouille There are times where an if statement negates the need for the `!` operator. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_VrulBiOV_o&t=15s at 6:02. I updated my example to show where sometimes it works and other times it doesn't?

Comment: @GuillaumeRoux. Weird. When I pasted into DartPad I still get the warnings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035574/null-check-doesnt-cause-type-promotion-in-dart