# Dart null safety conditional statement?

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

So I have a class `Cache` which has a method `compare` that returns a `bool`.

I have an instance of this class that is nullable.

```
Cache? recent;
```

I want to executed a piece of code when **`recent`** is `not null` and **`compare`** returns `false`

Without null safety I would have just done

```
if(recent!=null && !recent.compare()){
  //code
}
```

**How to do the same with null safety enabled?**

When I try above with null safety I get

> The method 'compare' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')

When I try below

```
if(!recent?.compare()){
  //code
}
```

It gives me

> A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.
> Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as a condition.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035574/ for why this happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this problem either by

- Using local variable (**recommended**)

  ```dart
  var r = recent; // Local variable
  if (r != null && !r.compare()) {
    // ...
  }
  ```
- Using Bang operator (`!`)

  ```dart
  if (!recent!.compare()) { 
    // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Or: `if(!(recent?.compare() ?? true))`

Comment: @julemand101 Right! You can also do that. It's difficult to find out all the possible cases ;) But in that case, you need to provide a default value which may not be the best way in general.

Comment: julemand101 I understand your approach, wasn't able to think about that :(. @CopsOnRoad I don't understand why the  local variable approach works, and also what is Bang operator. Thanks for your answer, I will read about these.

Comment: @coder_86 Since you're using Dart null-safety, you should use one of the approaches I've mentioned or even julemand101's. For more detailed answer, you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66941986/6618622)

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare the type as being
`dynamic recent;`
Which will match any 'data type' supplied at any given moment