# Flutter The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using image picker I need to store the image in the file so can show.

I am doing like this

```
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  PickedFile? _imageFile;
File? imageFile;


  _imgFromCamera() async {
    final pickedFile =
        await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 50);

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = pickedFile;
          imageFile = File(pickedFile!.path);

    });
  }

  _imgFromGallery() async {
    final pickedFile =
        await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery, imageQuality: 50);

    setState(() {
      _imageFile = pickedFile;
      imageFile = File(pickedFile!.path);

    });
  }
```

But when I am showing this

```
    Image.file(
        imageFile,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
      )
```

Its shows this error Flutter `The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'`. If I remove `?` from the File so it's showing some null safety errors.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the file to a new File Object.
Change this

```
File? imageFile;
```

to

```
File imageFile=new File('');
```

Answer (score 0):

`Image.file` needs a `File`, not a `File?`. Use a ternary operator to render `Image.file`:

```dart
imageFile != null ? Image.file(
  imageFile!,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
) : Text('imageFile is null'),
```

Comment: I am already showing image like this same error

Comment: which version of `image_picker` are you using?

Comment: [Non-local variables will not be automatically promoted by type checks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035574/).  Either use a local variable or use a null-assertion (`imageFile!`) after performing a null-check.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdlin! Updated my answer as per your suggestion.