# error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String', but null check doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm new to dart and flutter and I got this error:

error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

This error occurred when I tried to get fields of a user object from firebase and pass it to the User constructer. I tried the answer from another post, which is to do a null check on the returned user object and uid, but even inside the if statement dart still gives me this error.

Here is the function that the error occurred:

```
Future<UserSchema> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    var authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    return UserSchema(authResult.user.uid, authResult.user.email,
        authResult.user.displayName, authResult.user.password);
}
```

And this is the User class:

```
class UserSchema {
  String uid;
  String email;
  String displayName;
  String phoneNumber;
  String password;
  String city;
  String province;
  String postCode;
  bool hasTransit;
  String streetAddress;

  UserSchema(this.uid, this.email,this.displayName,this.password,
      {this.phoneNumber = '0000000000',
      this.postCode = '000000',
      this.streetAddress = '000 0000 0000',
      this.city = '00',
      this.province = '00',
      this.hasTransit = false});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
  'uid': uid.trim(),
  'displayName': displayName.trim(),
  'email': email.trim(),
  'phoneNumber': phoneNumber.trim(),
  'accountCreated':
    DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(Timestamp.now().toDate()),
    'shippingAddress': {
      'streetAddress': streetAddress.trim(),
      'city': city.trim(),
      'PostCode': postCode.trim(),
      'province': province.trim(),
    },
    'hasTransit': hasTransit,
  };
```

I would really appreciate a more detailed answer, thank you.

Comment: "even inside the `if` statement dart still gives me this error." You don't show the code where you do that, but you almost certainly checked a non-local variable.  Only *local* variables can be type-promoted.  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035574/

Answer (score 0):

It is hard for me to tell you the exact change you have to make because I am not super sure which variable has the error, regardless, I will explain to you what the error means, why it happens and how to properly deal with it.

### Why does this happen?

Some variable here is nullable that's to say it could be null, but you are trying to assign it to a non-nullable variable, so you get an error.

I am not sure which variable it is (or if it is more that one) so we will proceed assuming it is `authResult.user.email` for this example:

### How do I fix it?

To fix it, you can use the `!` operator. If you place the bang operator besides a nullable value, this error will disappear. But beware that if the value is in fact null, your app will crash. It is a dangerous operator that you should only use when you are certain the value will not be null.

```
authResult.user.email!
```

Another way to fix it is to provide some default value in case the original value is null, you can do this by using the  `??` operator:

```
authResult.user.email ?? 'example@email.com';
```

Just to be absolutely clear. I don't think you should give a default email value, it doesn't make sense for an email to have a default value. Also I believe `authResult.user.email` will only be null if the user uses anonymous sign In, so you should not have any problem with using `!`.