# dart wrongly assumes value can be nullable

Tags: android-studio, dart

I have the code

```
if (WORDLIST[language]==null) throw new Exception("Invalid Language");
List<String> wordlist = WORDLIST[language];
```

the compiler says

> Error: A value of type 'List?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List' because 'List?' is nullable and 'List' isn't.

However its both not possible in my code for language to be set to a value that is not valid and just to be safe there is the exception thrown if it gets called somewhere without checking the language exists.  How can I get the compiler to recognize this is valid?

Full Code is here(though the exception was added afterwards to try and handle new compiler):
https://github.com/mctrivia/bip39-multi/blob/mctrivia-patch-1/lib/src/bip39_multi_base.dart#L80

Comment: Can you show how you initialized WORDLIST variable?

Comment: https://github.com/mctrivia/bip39-multi/blob/mctrivia-patch-1/lib/src/bip39_multi_base.dart#L7

Comment: Because WORDLIST is Map<String,List<String>> you can possibly call a key that doesn't exist in the map. But checking for WORDLIST[language] doesn't prove it for IDE, but if you change it to if (!WORDLIST.containsKey(language)) throw new Exception("Invalid Language"); it should not complain anymore.

Comment: I did try that also.  But unfortunetly gets the same error

Comment: Well, as you are 100% sure and make the pre-check that the value exists in map, you can explicitly tell your IDE so by using exlamation mark ! like so:           List<String> wordlist = WORDLIST[language]!;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Map.operator []` returns a nullable type, period.  The compiler doesn't know what `WORDLIST[language]` will return at runtime; it doesn't know that `WORDLIST` isn't some `Map` implementation that returns different values each time `operator []` is called.  This is the same reason why [only local variables or private, `final` instance variables can be type promoted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035574/): the compiler can guarantee that the values are unchanged in those situations.

The typical ways to fix this are:

- Use `!` to force the result to be non-nullable:

  ```dart
  if (WORDLIST[language]==null) throw new Exception("Invalid Language");
  List<String> wordlist = WORDLIST[language]!;
  ```
- Use a local variable:

  ```dart
  var result = WORDLIST[language];
  if (result == null) throw new Exception("Invalid Language");
  List<String> wordlist = result;
  ```

  Since `wordlist` is probably already  a local variable, you also could just reorder your code:

  ```dart
  List<String>? wordlist = result;
  if (wordlist == null) throw new Exception("Invalid Language");
  // wordlist is now type-promoted to be List<String>.
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is not smart enough to promote general expressions, only local variable can be promoted.

When you write `if (WORDLIST[language] == null) throw ...`, that doesn't actually make the compiler any wiser wrt. the following `WORDLIST[language]` expression.
It takes specific knowledge about the implementation of the `[]` operator of `WORDLIST` to guarantee that it returns the same value every time it's called with the same argument. The compiler does not assume to have such knowledge.

What you should do is:

```dart
List<String>? wordlist = WORDLIST[language];
if (wordlist == null) {
  throw ArgumentError.value(language, "language", "Invalid language");
}
// use `wordlist` as `List<String>` here.
```

By assigning the value to a local variable, you allow the test+throw to promote that variable to non-nullable in the following (implicit else-branch) code.

Answer (score -2):

One way to hint to the compiler is to add an else clause, that way the compiler is sure the else branch will only execute when `WORDLIST[language]!=null`.

```
if (WORDLIST[language]==null) throw new Exception("Invalid Language");
else List<String> wordlist = WORDLIST[language];
```

Comment: That doesn't make any difference, the compiler can recognize that the `then` branch throws, so everything after can be treated as an `else` branch.