# Dart: How do I use "optional chaining" or a default value?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm coming from TypeScript to Dart because of Flutter and It's incredible how I can't do the simplest of things.

I have `style?.p?` as `double?` and I would like to read its value or use `0.0` as a default. Like this:

```
EdgeInsets.all(style?.p != null ? style.p : 0.0))
```

... but Dart is saying `double?` can't be assigned to `double`. Well, I'm using this ternary expression to check for `null`, but I think Dart is not as smart as TypeScript in type inference.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: try this EdgeInsets.all(style?.p ?? 0.0)

Comment: you can give the optional value like (optionalVaribaleValue  ?? DefaultValue) so if OptionalValue null then DefaultValue set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `EdgeInsets.all(style?.p != null ? style.p : 0.0))` doesn't work is because [only local variables or instance variables that both `final` and private can be type-promoted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035574/), and `style.p` is public, non-local variable. `style.p` therefore remains a `double?`, causing the evaluated type of the conditional ternary expression to also be `double?`.

Assigning `style?.p` to a local variable would work:

```dart
@override
void build(BuildContext context) {
  var p = style?.p;

  return ...
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(p != null ? p : 0));
}
```

but as others have noted (and as [the Dart linter recommends](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_if_null_operators.html)), you should prefer using a dedicated null operator:

```dart
padding: EdgeInsets.all(style?.p ?? 0);
```

where, because `style?.p` will not be evaluated multiple times (avoiding the potential for returning different values), `??` can evaluate to a non-nullable type.

Answer (score 4):

Try this
you can give the optional value like `(optionalVaribaleValue ?? DefaultValue)` so if OptionalValue null then DefaultValue set

```
EdgeInsets.all(style?.p ?? 0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your style attribute is nullable plus the p property is nullable too, try doing this:

```
padding: style != null
            ? EdgeInsets.all(style!.p != null ? style!.p! : 0.0)
            : const EdgeInsets.all(0.0)
```

Comment: You can also try what Vishal has suggested: EdgeInsets.all(style?.p ?? 0.0).