# i checked for null and still the null safety is bugging me in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```
              case ConnectionState.done:
                {
                  if (taskData.data != Null) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount : taskData.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          String task =
                              taskData.data[index]['task'].toString();
                          String day = DateTime.parse(
                                  taskData.data[index]['creationDate'])
                              .day
                              .toString();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
```

```
The property 'length' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
```

```
Missing case clause for 'none'.
Try adding a case clause for the missing constant, or adding a default clause.dart
```

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
```

im getting these errors

i checked in an if statement that supposed to be a solution but it didnt fix it
tried `Null` and `null` same issue

im still noob im sorry if its simple but couldnt find an answer

edit

```
 child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getTasks(),
              builder: (_, taskData) {
               if (taskData.data != null){
                print(taskData.data);
               }
}
```

```
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.
```

the error after making taskData

Comment: null is small letter n. the caps N is from dart:core

Comment: tried but didn't work

Comment: taskData.data!.length

Comment: @KaushikChandru The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'length', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'length'. gives this error

Comment: print taskdata.data and add it to the question please

Comment: @KaushikChandru i cannot print because it gives me error right after i initialized taskdata
The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end

Comment: inside connection state done, comment all codes and print(taskdata.data)

Comment: Can you include parent widget?

Comment: See https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons and https://stackoverflow.com/q/65035574/: null checks can promote only *local* variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide datatype on `FutureBuilder`/`StreamBuilder` and use `taskData.data?.length` on `itemCount`.

```dart
 FutureBuilder<List<ModelClass>?>(
builder: (context, taskData) {
//... others
  if (taskData.data != null) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: taskData.data?.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(""),
    );
  }
  // To handle body retun null
  return Text("");   
},
),
```

This error message show because you are your  `FutureBuilder` is missing default return.

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned,

Comment: I suggested this too @yeasin but he is mentioning that it isn't working

Comment: Got it he is missing default return part.