# How to cast an Object to Map (without using 'as')?

Tags: dart

Variable 'valor' is of type 'Object'.

'valor' stores a 'Map<String, String>'.

I can 'convert' valor to a Map using:

```
var json = valor as Map<String, String>;
```

The question is: Can I do the same thing without using 'as' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast without an *explicit* `as`, by going through dynamic.

```dart
dynamic dynamicValue = valor; // Valid up-cast.
Map<String, String> map = dynamicValue; // Implicit down-cast.
```

The implicit downcast is effectively an `as Map<String, String>` which is inserted by the compiler.

When compiling for the web, with "unsound optimizations" enabled, the implicit cast is optimized away and the compiler just blindly treats the value as a `Map<String, String>`, whether it is one or not.

If that's your goal, to avoid the cost of a cast at runtime, you can also just do:

```dart
Map<String, String> json = valor as dynamic;
```

That `as` is an up-cast, which is always sound and has no runtime overhead.

(Depending on your analyzer configuration, you may get warnings about implicit downcasts.)

Another approach, which doesn't use `as`, but does cost at runtime, is to use promotion:

```dart
Map<String, String> json;
if (valor is Map<String, String>) { // no `as`, but still a check.
  json = valor; 
} else {
  throw UnsupportedError("But it should be a map!");
}
// json is assigned here.
```

No use of `as`, but just as many type checks as `as Map<String, String>` does, so maybe not what you want anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but you can't, even method such as [`Iterable.cast()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-core/Iterable/cast.html) are using the `as` keyword under the hood.

You can check the [Dart type system documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system) for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You can and should check if `valor` is a `Map<String, String>` first and allow it to be automatically type-promoted:

```dart
if (valor is Map<String, String>) {
  // `valor` is now known to be a `Map<String, String>`.
  var json = valor;
  ...
}
```

Note that [type promotion can occur only for local variables or for `final`, private instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56764992/), so if `valor` is not local, you must create a local reference first.