# Get field from inherited class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a few classes that inherit from a base class. The inherited classes have fields that are not relevant for the other classes.

```
abstract class Game {}

class SingleplayerGame extends Game {
  int level;
}

class MultiplayerGame extends Game {
  int numberOfRounds;
}
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
Game game;
String title = game is MultiplayerGame 
  ? "Rounds: ${game.numberOfRounds.toString()}"
  : game is SingleplayerGame
    ? "Level: ${game.level.toString()}" : "";
```

I'm getting the error `The getter 'numberOfRounds' isn't defined for the type 'Game'`.

Comment: (game as MultiplayerGame).numberOfRounds, but make sure you checked the type before you do so

Comment: Your code should work fine if `game` is a local variable.  [Only local variables can be automatically type-promoted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56764592/).